# Cascading voltage regs not working as expected

Tags: power-supply, voltage, voltage-regulator, ldo

I was trying to hack together a power supply circuit with bits I had lying around but I didn't get the voltages I thought I would get, this is what I naively thought would happen:

[image]

But in reality the output from the lower (in the diagram) LDO goes up to around 22v as soon as the other one is connected. Why?

EDIT: In case it matters they are TI part no. LP2950-50LPRE3

EDIT2: I think one of my LDOs is failed to almost closed circuit. Thanks for the answers though!

Comment: Is that your complete circuit? that ti part needs a minimal output current to maintain regulation.

Comment: Well this was the bit I was testing, and is all I have built so far. So yes, to all intents and purposes this is the whole circuit. I have just tested it with a small load and there is no change. Thanks for the insight though.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Three-terminal linear regulators usually can't sink current - the 5 volt regulator can't pull the ground terminal of the 10 volt regulator down.  It can only pull its output up to 5 volts.

If you put a small load on the 5 volt line, that should pull the 5 volt line back down to 5 volts (if the load draws more than the 10 volt regulator's ground current).

If you are drawing any significant current from these regulators you *will* need a good heatsink.

I haven't look at the datasheet for those regulators, but you probably need input and output capacitors close to the regulators.

Answer (score -1):

load the regs to more than their idle current
Use idiot resistors in the Vin line
I have done this with 78l05 using 100 ohm resistors and 100n bypass caps the load was

about 3 mA   I got 5 and 10 vclt for a test jig 11` years ago